# Problem with updating table information by Simple HTML DOM and Fetch async / await

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, simple-html-dom

I have an HTML table whose cells are values that are called by `PHP Simple HTML DOM` script from several other sites and displayed inside the table, to update the values of each of my cells using JavaScript and jQuery, I did this:

my `index.php` page:

```
<?php include '../functions.php';?>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>My Page Title</title>

<!-- CSS -->
<link rel='stylesheet' href='../css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='../css/bootstrap-table.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='../css/bootstrap-editable.css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style1.css">
<!-- CSS -->


</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

<h1> my header </h1>
<p> some text </p>

<?php

    if (isset($_GET['value_A_1'])) {
        return value_A ('1');
    }
    if (isset($_GET['value_A_2'])) {
        return value_A ('2');
    }
    if (isset($_GET['value_A_3'])) {
        return value_A ('3');
    }
    if (isset($_GET['value_A_4'])) {
        return value_A ('4');
    }
    if (isset($_GET['value_A_5'])) {
        return value_A ('5');
    }
    if (isset($_GET['value_A_6'])) {
        return value_A ('6');
    }
?>

<script>
async function value_A(e) {
e.preventDefault(); 
document.getElementById('value_A_1').innerHTML = await(await fetch('?value_A_1=1')).text();
document.getElementById('value_A_2').innerHTML = await(await fetch('?value_A_2=1')).text();
document.getElementById('value_A_3').innerHTML = await(await fetch('?value_A_3=1')).text();
document.getElementById('value_A_4').innerHTML = await(await fetch('?value_A_4=1')).text();
document.getElementById('value_A_5').innerHTML = await(await fetch('?value_A_5=1')).text();
document.getElementById('value_A_6').innerHTML = await(await fetch('?value_A_6=1')).text();
}
</script>




    <table style="border: 1px solid #333;border-collapse: collapse;padding: 8px;width: 100%;max-width: 100%;border-spacing: 0;overflow:hidden;">
        
        <tbody>
            <tr style="border: 1px solid #333;border-collapse: collapse;">

                <td style="border: 1px solid #333;border-collapse: collapse;"><a href="" onclick="value_A(event);">Update Button</a></td>
                <td id="value_A_1" style="border: 1px solid #333;border-collapse: collapse;">...</td>
                <td id="value_A_2" style="border: 1px solid #333;border-collapse: collapse;">...</td>
                <td id="value_A_3" style="border: 1px solid #333;border-collapse: collapse;">...</td>
                <td id="value_A_4" style="border: 1px solid #333;border-collapse: collapse;">...</td>
                <td id="value_A_5" style="border: 1px solid #333;border-collapse: collapse;">...</td>
                <td id="value_A_6" style="border: 1px solid #333;border-collapse: collapse;">...</td>


            </tr>

            other rows
            .
            .
            .

        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>


And the rest of the page components
```

Now when the update button is pressed, the functions (`value_A ('x')`) I wrote based on `PHP Simple HTML DOM`  run well and the values of each table cell are displayed in it.
But I have two problems:

1. When the cell value wants to be updated, in addition to displaying the output value of the php function inside the cell, the rest of the page components are strangely displayed again inside that cell of the table, for example:

```
<h1> my header </h1>
<p> some text </p>
```

Are displayed inside each cell again!

2. I want a loading text or image to be displayed to the user until the php output is processed and ready to be displayed, and that text or image disappears when the php output is ready

Please help me if you have a solution to these two problems.